# How to Interract with Knockoutjs Variables | Magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

1) I'm trying to filter the customer addresses in the checkout according to their postal code. The address blocks are displayed using the following knockoutjs code:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html

```
<!-- ko if: (visible)-->
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="shipping-address-items">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
                <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

First thing, I'm struggling to understand where the **elems** variable comes from. Where should I be looking for its declaration?

2) Then I've been able to retrieve the postcode from the **element** object, and add a comparison to a hardcoded value. The following code works, only displaying the addresses whose postal code is 12345:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko if: (element.address().postcode === "12345") -->
        <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

But how can I pass a value from php or jQuery (or a knockoutjs selector?) to use as my comparison instead of the hardcoded string?

Comment: Welcome to hell (the Magento 2 checkout), you must have been a bad person to get here.

Comment: @BenCrook, Caught right one !!

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress here, for some reason I expected the list.html to work with the list.js, but  within the foreach tag I needed to use address-renderer/default.js

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js

In this file I've been able to declare a function returning the postal code I needed from the known quote object. In the list.html I've simply called this function in my condition, and it works (both files copied in my local theme).

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko if: (element.address().postcode === getPostalcode()) -->
        <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

So I still don't know where the elems variable comes from, but at least I've been able to retrieve my value from existing js objects!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uicollection_concept.html

> elems is the observable property that contains the collection of child UI components.

```
console.log(this.elems());

// [
//   %uiComponentInstance 1 %,
//   %uiComponentInstance 2 %,
//   %uiComponentInstance 3 %,
//   %uiComponentInstance 4 %
// ]
```

If you search for `elems` inside `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/collection.js` you will find a few functions that can populate this collection. Such as:

- `_insert` - Inserts provided component into 'elems' array at a specified position.
- `_updateCollection` - Synchronizes multiple elements arrays with a core '_elems' container.
- `insertChild` - Requests specified components to insert them into 'elems' array starting from provided position.

I've also answered a similar question here that has a bit more info - [Magento 2: What Populates "elems" in a UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124782/magento-2-what-populates-elems-in-a-ui-component)

To pass data through to this I believe you'd need to extend and edit `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml:160`

```
<item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-list</item>
</item>
```

I haven't ever passed data in this way so I can't help much more here sorry. Hopefully this helps slightly.